# Brightcove library keeps crashing the application

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector, brightcove

I have implemented the **brightcove** library 4.2.1 in my iOS App.

My application is crashing over line:

```
self.player = [[BCOVPlayerSDKManager sharedManager] createPlaybackControllerWithViewStrategy:nil];
```

**Error:**

> [BCOVBasicPlaybackController BCOV_rac_valuesForKeyPath:observer:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b394890
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[BCOVBasicPlaybackController
>   BCOV_rac_valuesForKeyPath:observer:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x7b394890'

Any idea what's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `-ObjC` in other Linker flags

Comment: Thanks. I missed it accidentally.